# python - unsupported operand types

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im new on Python, and I got this error, someone can help me ?

```
 int(PR = PC + I);
```

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple`

how can I fix that

att1- here is the full code, sorry

```
 CC = int(input("Informe o código de carga do caminhão: "));
PT = int(input("Informe o peso do caminhão em toneladas: "));
CE = int(input("Informe o código de Estado referente ao estado de origem do caminhão: "));
P = PT * 1000;
print("O peso em quilos do caminhão é de", P,"kg");
if CC == 10:
    PC = 100*P
else:
    if CC == 20:
        PC = 200*P
    else:
        if CC == 30:
            PC = 300*P
        else:
            print("Código inválido");
if CE == 1:
    IP = 0,3*PC
else:
    if CE == 2:
        IP = 0,1*PC
    else:
        if CE == 3:
            IP = 0
        else:
            print("Código inválido");
PR = PC + IP;
print("O preço da carga é de R$", PC,);
print("O imposto cobrado foi de R$", IP,);
print("O preço total é de R$", PR,);
```

the idiom on the code is BR-PORTUGUESE, not english, but it doesnt interfere on the understading of the code

Comment: `PR = PC + I`: either `PC`, `I` is a tuple, not int. Can you please provide your full code to avoid attracting more downvotes?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and the other links on that page, especially [mcve].

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception you should always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k).  In your question, the line of code you referenced is not in the code you posted.  If you just copy and paste the Traceback, that won't happen.

Comment: `IP = 0,3*PC` creates the tuple `(0, 3 * PC)`. Did you mean `IP = 0.3 * PC` ?

Comment: PM 2Ring, omg, that worked LMAO, i started to use python a few time ago and too much times I forgot that is 0.3 not 0,3. Tks man !!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new to Python, but it looks like your PC variable is an int, while your I variable is a tuple, which is Python's data type for something like (2,1) or (1,2,3). If your I is just a single integer represented as a tuple like (3,), you can probably do something like:

```
int(PR = PC + int(I[0]))
```

which will get the 0th item in the tuple and represent it as an integer.

(Or if PC is the tuple and I is the int, you switch it around)

Comment: I tried this and doesnt worked, on my case, PC and I are integers variables.

Comment: When I tried that u said, appears that: TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable